# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int' (CS0019)

Tags: c#

I get the error in the title when i do this:

```
else if (celsius<73 != 0) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tyvärr så är " + celsius + "° för låg temperatur, ställ in värmen mellan 73 till 77 grader."); //
    Console.Write("Välj temperatur igen : ");
```

I want it to come out false if celsius is 0, sry for my bad english.

Comment: `celsius<73` can be true or false, 0 is an integer

Answer (score 4):

> I want it to come out false if celsius is 0

If you want to do multiple comparisons against a variable, they need to be specified separately.

Thus:

```
else if (celsius<73 != 0)
```

should instead be:

```
else if (celsius<73 && celsius != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare a `bool`(which is what `celsius<73` returns) with an integer 0.

I think you want that celsius is <73 **and** != 0:

```
else if (celsius < 73 && celsius != 0) 
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is true ....

> I want it to come out false if celsius is 0, sry for my bad english.

... then change it to:

```
if (celsius != 0)
{
}
```